# How do I send a Twilio SMS api post correctly from Arduino UNO WiFi

Tags: twilio, sms, wifi, arduino-uno

I am trying to send an SMS message to a phone using an Arduino UNO WiFi board and the Twilio API.
I can get connected to my WiFi and to the Twilio server using WiFiNINA library.

I've base64 encoded the `userid` and auth string and tried to send the correct info to the API but get bad request errors. None of the Twilio examples show a C program sending the strings necessary to satisfy the API.

This is the code fragment used to do the Post (with some data xxx'd out):

```
client.println("POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb247exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json");
client.println(authstring);
client.println("From, +14084098202");
client.println("Body, first test message");
client.println("To, +1408xxxyyyy");
```

An example of how to properly send this using the `client.println` function from the library would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you receive?

Comment: I modified the post as follows, now get no error messages, just no response:  client.println("POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb247exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb537/Messages.json HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: api.twilio.com");
      client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println(authstring);  // the base64 encoded userid and auth string
      client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      client.print("Content-Length: ");
      client.println(bodylen);
      client.println(body); // to, from & message